# Stopping hover() mid way

Tags: jquery, attributes, hover, mouseover

I animate a Dashboard (a div) which is hidden until `hover()` takes effect. mouseOver the div appears, mouseOut the div is hidden again, plain and simple - it works well.

But I want to add another feature. Can I stop the mouseOut function somehow i.e. `click()` so that I can move the mouse outside the div without it disappearing like it is supposed? And afterwards with the same `click()` function to resume the normal runtime of the `hover()` function?

My code for the hover (just in case):

```
$('#dashboard').hover( function () {
                        $(this).stop().animate ({left: '0',backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)'},400,'easeInSine'); //animate M.over
                                },
                     function () {
                        $(this).stop().animate ({left: '-92px',backgroundColor: 'rgb(110,138,195)'},900,'easeOutBounce'); //animete M.out
                                }); // end hover
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set a flag when you click and check that flag whenever you enter or leave the element.

```
var disabled = false;

$('#dashboard').click(function () {
    // toggle the disabled
    disabled = !disabled;

}).hover(function () {
    if (!disabled) {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            left: '0',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)'
        }, 400, 'easeInSine'); //animate M.over
    }
},
function () {
    if (!disabled) {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            left: '-92px',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(110,138,195)'
        }, 900, 'easeOutBounce'); //animete M.out
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R2PeL/1/